# Implementation of random_spanning_tree using BGL

Tags: c++, boost, random-seed

I am facing some problem in implementation of random_spanning_tree.

How to initialise random number generator?

```
   boost::uniform_int<> rng(0,9);
   boost::random::random_number_generator <boost::uniform_int<>, long> 
                                        gen(rng);

   boost::random_spanning_tree(g, gen,
                          boost::root_vertex(1).predecessor_map(&p[0])
                         ) ;
```

This is link : https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/graph/doc/random_spanning_tree.html
What should be model of `gen` argument to run this function?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I completely disagree with the close reason given here. The question could be more clearly asked, but given the subject matter and available docs I'm not suprised that the question couldn't be posed more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that you should just pass an engine as the generator.

Example

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/daea8c7ec226ea3f)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/random_spanning_tree.hpp>
#include <random>

int main() {
    using G = boost::adjacency_list<>;

    std::mt19937 gen;
    //std::uniform_int_distribution<> rng(0,9);

    G g(10);
    add_edge(1, 2, g);
    add_edge(2, 3, g);
    add_edge(2, 6, g);
    add_edge(6, 4, g);
    std::vector<G::vertex_descriptor> p(num_vertices(g));

    boost::random_spanning_tree(g, gen, boost::root_vertex(1).predecessor_map(&p[0])); 
}
```

Which will predictable fail with a `boost::loop_erased_random_walk_stuck` exception.